# Unable to set up an Envoy Front Proxy on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to set up an envoy front proxy using envoy sidecar containers on Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) referring to this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-an-envoy-front-proxy-on-amazon-ecs/).

The envoy sidecar configuration is :

```
#service-envoy.yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service"
                route:
                  cluster: local_service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: local_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: 127.0.0.1
        port_value: 8080
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8081
```

Front proxy envoy configuration :

```
#front-envoy.yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
           name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                 prefix: "/service"
                route:
                  cluster: testservice
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: testservice
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        # this is the ecs service discovery endpoint for our service 
        address: testservice.ecs
        port_value: 80         
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

I am able to set and test the envoy as sidecar but the envoy front proxy keep giving me http error code 503 consistently.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the ECS Cluster service namespaces, I created a unique namespace and assigned all of my cluster services under that namespace and it started to work.

Earlier I was taking default cluster service namespace that was somehow not working.

Comment: was it a private dns or public dns namespace?